# Discord.js - Create channel and give specific user all permissions for the channel

Tags: javascript, node.js, permissions, discord.js

I'm currently working on a bot that creates a channel for a user and gives him admin permissions for the created channel.
My current code is not working correctly. The user is getting a own entry in the channel permissions but has not a single permission. For example he cant even talk.

```
        newState.guild.channels.create(channelName, {
            type:"GUILD_VOICE",
            parent: parentId,
            position: 1,
            permissionOverwrites: [{
                id:member,
                allow: ["ADMINISTRATOR"]
            }]
        })
```

I am very grateful for help

Answer (score 0):

`Administrator` is not a permission for any type of channels [voice/text] in discord

```js
 newState.guild.channels.create(channelName, {
            type:"GUILD_VOICE",
            parent: parentId,
            position: 1,
            permissionOverwrites: [{
                id: member,
                allow: ["CONNECT", "SPEAK"]
            }]
        })
```